# How to use a UserControl in my application without building it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to use a usercontrol I found on the web in my WPF application. The thing is that I don't want to have to put it in a user control library and build it and then reference that. I just want to be able to import the files into my project and use it from there.

So what I have done is dragged the files into the solution explorer, and it added them okay. I then changed the namespaces to match my own and then attempted to add it to the main forms xaml(This is where my issue is.)

It says the type "local:Pie" is not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference...and you know the rest.

Here is how I am calling it on my main for xaml:

```
<Grid>
        <local:Pie Value="0" x:Name="pieChart" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="400" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>
        <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,0,50,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Slider Orientation="Vertical" Minimum="0" Maximum="1" TickFrequency="0.01" Height="272" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged_1" Value="0" Name="slider"/>            
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Here is the controls XAML with my application namespace added:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApplicationNAmespace.Pie"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded_1" SizeChanged="UserControl_SizeChanged_1">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse Name="bgCircle"/>
        <Path Name="path" StrokeThickness="1.5" Margin="0"/>
        <Ellipse Name="hole" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.45" ScaleY="0.45"/>
            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        </Ellipse>
        <Label Content="Value" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
               FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="38" Name="lblValue"
               VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

For the codebehind of the control all I have changed was the namespace to match my projects namespace.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: *Where* is "the controls XAML with [your] application namespace added"?

Comment: That said, have you declared the namespace prefix `local` to point to the namespace of your control *in your main form's XAML*?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Oops, I forgot to add the codeblocks around it so it did not show up. I have edited my post.

Comment: As O.R. said, are you declaring the `local` namespace within the main form XAML?